# Multiple promises on function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this socket, when I received a message I check the user, if user didn't exist:
I add to array and console.log("Hey new user:" + results.get("name"))
if already exist i just put:
console.log('User Already Exist!')

The problem is sometimes i received 2 messages too fast from the same user, and when this happen Parse user check is not resolved yet and add the user 2 times how can I do a promise to wait last onmessage solve before continue?

```
socket.onmessage = function(dataObject)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(dataObject.data);

    user = obj.user;
    var index = getIndexOf($scope.users, user);

    if(index === false)
    {   
        Parse.getUser(user).then(function(results)
        {   
            $scope.addUser(results.id, results.get("name"), results.get("image")).then(function()
            {   
                console.log("Hey new user:" + results.get("name"))
            }); 
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('User Already Exist!')
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Also do the `getIndexOf` check inside of the callback to `Parse`.

```
Parse.getUser(user).then(function(results)
{
    if (getIndexOf($scope.users, results) === false) {
        $scope.addUser(results.id, results.get("name"), results.get("image")).then(function()
        {   
            console.log("Hey new user:" + results.get("name"));
        });
    }
});
```